# Vuejs Computed Property warns that I have no setter

Tags: vuejs2, computed-properties

I have a code like this:

```
<button
  @click="addFieldRow"
  :disabled="disableAddRow"
>
```

`disableAddRow` is a computed property like this:

```
disableAddRow() {
  if (this.currentIndex !== null) {
    return !this.fieldList[this.currentIndex].filterApplied;
  }
  if (this.currentIndex === null && this.fieldList.length === 1) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Works as it should, but on my console log, I get the following warning:

> [Vue warn]: Computed property "disableAddRow" was assigned to but it
>   has no setter.

I don't get why I need a setter? And if I do need a setter, I don't understand what I need to set...

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: That warning means that, somewhere in your code, you are assigning a value to your `disableAddRow` computed property. The code you shared wouldn't cause that warning, so you must be inadvertently assigning it a value somewhere else.

Comment: @thanksd Wow I am dumb. I was originally using `disableAddRow` as a non computed prop, I forgot I set a value else where. Could you add this as an answer, so I can mark it as answered? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That warning is indicating that, somewhere in your code, you are assigning a value to your `disableAddRow` computed property.

The code you shared wouldn't cause that warning, so you must be inadvertently assigning it a value somewhere else. You simply need to not set the value of the computed property and you won't get that warning anymore.

---

For a little more context: computed properties, by default, retrieve the value returned by the defining function. It is, however, possible to define [setters for computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) as well (which is what the warning is alluding to).